# SQL database checklist

Tags: sql

I need to create a Sql Database Checklist,
I have some basics points like

- Each table must have a primary key
- Normalize data to third normal form
- Check for Integrity column the column value should be incremented properly.

But can anyone help me to enhance this list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Objects conform to a single naming convention
- Create foreign key relationships
- Apply appropriate index(es)
- Use of schema or other mechanisms for controlling read/write access, etc
- Consideration given to how long data should be kept before deletion or archive
- Version control over scripts for updating the database structure
- Mechanism for applications to determine version of database
- Backup and recovery plans in place

Answer (score 1):

First, It would help if this is supposed to be a recuring check list, or a checklist for each new instance.  Also, is there a specific implementation in mind like SQL Server? MySQL? (this is where the real check list begins).  For example, you want to keep an eye on the Transactions Log if its SQL Server...

If this is a relational DB, ER diamgrams go a long way in making sure that you have your problem domain identified and analyzed.  You are right track using third normal form where practical.   I want to emphasize practical because you also want to try and anticipate and identify which data will be used more than others.  If data is highly accessed, you may want consider indexing more than just the primary and/or denormalizing to 2nd normal form. (uses more space, but better performance).  Remember that accessing data and updating data are inversely related when indexing is concerned.  Hope this helps.